# Canvas: add overlay except button that should be clickable

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to add an overlay using canvas. It needs to disable clicks so all elements above the overlay should be unclickable, except the element that I send to openOverlay function.

In addition, there is a button that I want to make it clickable. This button is sent to openOverlay function.

How can I do it?

This is my code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQqQae
The button needs to be clickable but not the div

I tried something like: `ctx.clearRect` in order to cut the piece that is found above the button:

```
function openOverlay(elem) {
  var loc = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.className = "highlight";
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.clearRect(loc.left - padding, loc.top - padding, loc.width + padding * 2, loc.height + padding * 2);
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  window.overlayCanvas = canvas;
}
```

Comment: This is unclear - what's the overlay supposed to look like?   What even *is* this overlay?

Comment: I didn't mention but the overlay needs to disable clicks..

Comment: So all elements above the overlay should be unclickable, except the element that I sent to openOverlay function.

Answer (score 0):

Set z-index for "canvas" to -1 :

```
canvas{
  z-index: -1;
}
```

But, the above method will make all the elements in the canvas clickable.

So, you can set the following style on the button to make it clickable :

```
button{
  position: absolute; //or, relative
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

All the other elements in the canvas won't be clickable unless they have position absolute (or, relative) and higher z-index.

Comment: Thanks but maybe I don"t make the question clear.. I updated the topic..

Comment: I see your question is changed. But, still the above solution will work. you can make the button's position absolute (or, relative) and set a higher z-index. All the other elements in the canvas won't be clickable unless they have position absolute (or, relative) and higher z-index.

Answer (score 0):

First, ctx.clearRect doesn't really have any effect on the mouse click event. 
In the future, you may be able to use canvas hit regions, but they have limited support for now. See [MDN AddHitRegion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion)

But for now, you can put any button that is supposed to be clickable at a higher z-index than the overlay and give it either relative or absolute positioning.

```js
function openOverlay(elem) {

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.className = "highlight";
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.zIndex = 100;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillRect(4, 4, 300, 150);
  elem.classList.add("clickable");
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  window.overlayCanvas = canvas;
}
var element= document.getElementById("button1")
openOverlay(element)
```

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
}

.clickable{
  position: relative;
  z-index:200;
}
canvas{
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color:blue;  
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="window.alert('Clicked button1')">Click Me</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="window.alert('Clicked button 2')">Don't Click Me</button>
```